# Clip GridLines outside of a circle

Tags: graphics, grid-lines

```
Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

This puts grids across a 2D graphic (a circle here).

Is there any way to specify the range of values of `GridLines`? More specifically I want the part of `GridLines` that are inside the circle. That is the part of them that is outside the circle should be removed.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`FilledCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledCurve) to create a graphics primitive with a hole in it. For example:

```
Graphics[
    {
    White,
    FilledCurve[{
        {Line[{Scaled[{0,0}],Scaled[{1,0}],Scaled[{1,1}],Scaled[{0,1}],Scaled[{0,0}]}]},
        {Line@CirclePoints[.5, 100]}
    }],
    Blue,
    Circle[{0,0},.5]
    },
    Frame -> True,
    GridLines -> Automatic
]
```

[image]

**Update**

My previous answer let the grid lines from the underlying [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) option show through the hole in the [`FilledCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledCurve). If you want the grid lines to be rotated, then another approach using [`Texture`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture) and [`FilledCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledCurve) would work better. [`FilledCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledCurve) supports [`Line`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line), [`BezierCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BezierCurve) and [`BSplineCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineCurve) segments. The documentation provides an example for creating a circle from a [`BSplineCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineCurve), so I will use that:

```
bSplineCircle[c_, r_] := Module[{pts=TranslationTransform[c][r $CirclePoints]},
    BSplineCurve[
 pts,
 SplineDegree->2,
 SplineKnots->$CircleKnots,
        SplineWeights->$CircleWeights
    ]
]

$CircleKnots = {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1};
$CircleWeights = {1, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5, 1};
$CirclePoints = {{0,-1},{1,-1},{1,1},{0,1},{-1,1},{-1,-1},{0,-1}};
$CircleTextureCoordinates = {{.5,0},{1,0},{1,1},{.5,1},{0,1},{0,0},{.5,0}};
```

Example:

```
Graphics[{bSplineCircle[{-1,1},1], bSplineCircle[{1,-1},.5]}, Axes->True]
```

[image]

Using the above `bSplineCircle` function we can create a `texturedCircle` function:

```
texturedCircle[c_, r_, texture_, rot_:0] :={
    Texture[texture],
    FilledCurve[
        {bSplineCircle[c, r]},
        VertexTextureCoordinates -> RotationTransform[rot, {.5, .5}] @ $CircleTextureCoordinates
    ]
}
```

Here is an example using `texturedCircle`:

```
Graphics[
    {
    EdgeForm[Blue],
    texturedCircle[{1, 2}, 1, Graphics[{}, GridLines->Automatic], Pi/8],
    EdgeForm[Green],
    texturedCircle[{3, 4}, .5, Graphics[{}, GridLines->Automatic]],
    EdgeForm[None],
    texturedCircle[{3, 1}, 1, ExampleData[{"TestImage","Lena"}], Pi/4]
    },
    Axes->True
]
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much. Is is possible also to modify the orientation of these grid lines (for instance by π/4 rad)?

Answer (score 5):

You may also use parametric plot which can give more flexibility (like the pi/4 rotation you want):

```
pt = {Table[
     ParametricPlot[{x, x + a}, {x, 1/2 (-a - Sqrt[2 - a^2]), 
       1/2 (-a + Sqrt[2 - a^2])}], {a, -1, 1, .5}], 
    Table[ParametricPlot[{x, -x + a}, {x, 1/2 (a - Sqrt[2 - a^2]), 
       1/2 (a + Sqrt[2 - a^2])}], {a, -1, 1, .5}]} // Flatten;

Show[{pt, Graphics[Circle[]]}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

where the x range for the gridlines are from

```
Solve[x + a == Sqrt[1 - x^2], x]
Solve[-x + a == Sqrt[1 - x^2], x]
```

Comment: Thanks! How can we modify the code in order to have the center of circle (and the grids translated) to (0.5,0.5)?